# Midnight commander freezes when lynx navigation is used in a quick fashion

Tags: performance, iterm

As a wrote in the title I use MC on Mac because I just like it and it is a very effective tool, especially with lynx-like navigation. But it gets frozen randomly when I use it basically running through a directory structure. I don't know any other tool which is as effective as MC can be. Finder is not my way in this case.

The phenomena is independent from terminal app. It happens in iTerm2 and Hyper too.

The other thing I experience with MC is that it starts slowly, it takes 3-5 seconds to start. I don't know whether the two are related.

Is anyone experienced similar and has any idea what to do to MC avoid freeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is describe here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57439/slow-start-of-midnight-commander For me the `mc --nosubshell` worked.

Both problem are solved. MC starts verz quickly and no sign of freezes when I use Lynx-like navigation quickly.